# AWS JS SDK Exception Information

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I'm having trouble finding documentation about errors in the AWS SDK beyond a few sentences in this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html#troubleshooting). I am not able to find any docs for what properties an error may contain, what errors are likely to be thrown by specific operations like s3:GetObject, or any sample code which does good error handling. Apart from failing on purpose and seeing what errors result, are there better ways?

Comment: Log the error message to determine what the issue is. Most error messages are detailed enough to figure out.

Comment: @smac2020 not sure that's the point of the question. It's how to know what the list of possible failures can be so that you can decide which you want to handle explicitly. You cannot possibly cause AWS to generate all the potential errors that could occur for any given SDK/API call, not least because you don't have any way of knowing what all the error scenarios are (because they're not documented). The consequence is that you have to run code to trigger the common errors, but all the others are largely unknowable so you end up with some generic handler that logs the failure and stops.